# Unzip flat file and than store it in DB

Tags: foreach, ssis, zip, unzip

I have some doubt on SSIS package. 
I want to unzip multiple file and load in MSSQL table, all the file having different schema.
i need to it in 1 package. 
Can this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, I dont know how you different these files and how to map them to table, for example that you use File Name to detect, u can put this file name as condition in arrow line. and split them different Data Flow.

Comment: Each file schema will need its own data flow. You need to determine which file type it is and send it down that path.

Comment: You will either need to know all the flat file schemas beforehand, so you can define them as would be used by BeiBei_ZHU or KeithL, or, if you won't know the schema beforehand, you will need to write a custom script component to parse and extract the data. In any case, you'll still need to come up with to identify the files, as KeithL states.

Comment: I have done this work, unzip file and than add one execute process task after that and call a store procedure which having insert scripts